# Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Date>' to expected argument type 'Date'

Tags: date, swiftui, binding

I'm trying pass date use Binding.
This is where i'm getting this error next to Text

> Cannot convert value of type 'Binding' to expected argument type 'Date'

if I remove style: .date  i'm getting another error

> Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Binding' conform to 'StringProtocol'

```
struct ProfileView<ViewModel: ViewModelType>: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel    
    @State var selectedDate: Date = Date()
    
    init(with viewModel: ViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text( Binding<Date>(
                get: { viewModel.selectedDate },
                set: { _ in viewModel.setDate(selectedDate) }), style: .date )

        }
    }
}
```

```
final class ViewModel: ViewModelType {
    
    var selectedDate: Date = Date()
    
    func setDate(_ selectedDate: Date) {
        self.selectedDate = selectedDate
    }
}
```

```
 DatePicker("", selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: .date)
```

```
protocol ViewModelType: ObservableObject {
       
    var selectedDate: Date { get }
    func setDate(_ selectedDate: Date)
    
}
```

I wold like set the date use func setDate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get is because your `Text(...)` in `ProfileView` requires a `Date`, but you are giving it a `Binding<Date>`.

I suggest you try the following code to set the `selectedDate` in your
`ViewModel`. The `@Published var selectedDate: Date` will get updated
automatically in your views, whenever the `viewModel` is changed. There is no need for a separate `func setDate(...)`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ProfileView(viewModel: viewModel)
            DatePicker("", selection: $viewModel.selectedDate, displayedComponents: .date)
        }
    }
}

struct ProfileView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(viewModel.selectedDate, style: .date )
        }
    }
}

final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedDate: Date = Date()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI we only pass in the data the View needs so it should be

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    
    let selectedDate: Date
    
    var body ...
}
```